# Extjs Combobox Autocomplete

Tags: extjs4

I am using Extjs 4 ComboBox with remote mode. but when i typed any character data is not filtered. and even focus is changed only for first 12 value.[image: combobox image]

I am new to Extjs 4. Please help me how to do this.

my code is:

```
    Ext.define('MyGroup.combo', {
           extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',

           alias: 'widget.mycombo',
        emptyText:'select keyword',
        store: keywordStore,
        valueField:'name',
           displayField:'name',
           mode: 'remote',
           autoSelect: false,
           selectOnFocus:true,
           //shadow:true,
           //forceSelection: false,
           //triggerAction: 'all',
           hideTrigger:true,
           //multiSelect:true,
           typeAhead:true,
        minChars:1
       });

       Ext.define('keywordModel', {
           extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
           proxy: {
               type: 'ajax',
               url : '/keywordServlet',
               method:'POST',
               reader: {
                   type: 'json',
                   root: 'rows'
                   //,totalProperty: 'totalCount'
               }
           },

           fields: [
               {name: 'name', mapping: 'name'}
           ]
       });

          var keywordStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
             // pageSize: 10,
              model: 'keywordModel'
          });
```

Comment: Why you are using define?Shall you post how you are calling this combo?

Comment: i am caling this as xtype:'mycombo'

Comment: Have you tried with normal combobox i mean without using mucombo.Is it working fine(filter)?

Comment: If you are trying to override the combobox then this is not the correct way to override.

Comment: which is the correct way? can u provide me a sample?

Comment: first of all let me know what you are trying to do?are you trying to override combobox or else you can use normal combobx in your application

Comment: Kiran, here i am extending a combobox and reuse that multiple time in my project. to make it reusable i am using define, and that is the only way to reuse. If you are unaware about this, please stay away from this question. It is not compulsory to answer each and every question.

Comment: Ram,You didnt mentioned that in question that why am asking there is lot of difference between overriding a component and extending a component.

Answer (score 3):

As per my knowledge i think this will be helpful for you:

```
Ext.define('MyGroup.combo', {
           extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
           alias: 'widget.mycombo',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent([arguments]);
    }
});

var keywordStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.SimpleStore',{
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
    data: [[1, 'mr'],[2, 'mr(yes)'],[3, 'mr(no)'], [4, 'example'], [5, 'example(yes)'],[6,'example(no)'],[7,'sample'],[8,'sample(yes)'],[9,'sample(no)'],[10,'mrs'],[11,'mrs(yes)'],[12,'mrs(no)']]
});

Ext.widget('mycombo',{
    xtype : 'combo',
        emptyText:'select keyword',
        store: keywordStore,
        valueField:'name',
           displayField:'name',
           mode: 'remote',
           autoSelect: false,
           selectOnFocus:true,
           //shadow:true,
           //forceSelection: false,
           //triggerAction: 'all',
           hideTrigger:true,
           //multiSelect:true,
           typeAhead:true,
        minChars:1,
    renderTo :document.body
       });
```

And one more thing is no one is trying to answer each and every question,but every one is trying to help some body like us:-)

Comment: Very nice post!  Few questions regarding this code (I'll +1 your comments) ... can you have it auto-complete the text so it'll do either "starts with" or "partial match" logic, and only show 5 or 10 results after doing so?